# How to remove specific pages in a word docx?

Tags: asp.net, openxml, docx, openxml-sdk

I would like to delete/remove specific pages in a word docx with Open XML SDK 2.0.

I have tried using the code from here: [blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2009/06/15/removing-page-and-section-breaks-from-a-word-document.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2009/06/15/removing-page-and-section-breaks-from-a-word-document.aspx)

It only deletes all the section breaks. The pages are still not deleted.

I want to delete a set of pages which has specific set of words or titles.

Please let me know how can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't think you can delete a page. Because pages determined by text size and images in it, etc. You can delete certain text.

Comment: Could the OP delete the text defined by a bookmark or something? That might be useful in the case where it's a special-purpose page, which does not flow.

Comment: I see. Ok, another alternative I thought is: merging the required set of single page docx files into one? How well would that work? Will it will merge accurately as though you insert separate pages in a doc?

Comment: yes, merging single files should work well. instead of removing a page from the word document

Comment: Is the open xml sdk a necessary requirement ?

Comment: I couldn't find any other open source free sdk to fill data into word doc from asp.net. Open XML seems like the only option with free and unlimited access. I have several word doc files (docx) each with content control fields now. I use open xml to insert data into each docx file. I then tried to merge with required docx file using http://powertools.codeplex.com/ but it didn't work. It came with error: "Sequence contains no elements" in the DocumentBuilder. It seems that DocumentBuilder does not support content control and custom xml binding for merging docx files...How to solve this?